# How to achieve "Insert or Increment" in one MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I want to write a query in MongoDB to insert a object in a document if it doesn't exist or increment a certain field of it if it exists in the specified document. There are two queries follows as an example:

Documents Structures:

```
     Movies:
     {
         integer _id,
         string Name,
         array(object) WatchingList
         [
            {
                integer UserID,
                integer WatchTimes
            }
            .....
         ]
     }
```

Insert Query:

```
db.Movies.update({_id:x}, {$push: {WatchingList:{UserID:y,WatchTimes:1}}});
```

Increment Query:

```
db.Movies.update({_id:x,"WatchingList.UserID":y},{$inc:{"WatchingList.$.WatchTimes":1}});
```

How can I combine them together into one or more queries to acheive the requirement?

Comment: May I see your document structure? From what I see, you blundered with your model already and we should correct that before doing anything else.

Comment: I've added the document structure, you can have a look.

Comment: Increase the watchtimes first and then update? I mean fetch watchtimes do a +1 and then update.

Comment: @Abhishek Dey Yeah, you can do that. but you need to ensure that the two queries I have wrote can be combined together.

Comment: @AbhishekDey which wouldn't be atomic and susceptible to race conditions.

Comment: How about using promises or maintaining a counter? But then again turning nodejs to synchronous is the last thing we want. See this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ @MarkusWMahlberg

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine for me with the node.js 3.x mongodb driver:

```
await db.collection('collection-name').updateOne({name:"foo"}, {$inc:{counter:10}}, {upsert:true});
```

If a doc with `name=foo` doesn't exist it creates it and sets the counter to 10. If it already exists then it adds 10 to the counter.

If you need to execute a bunch of commands at once, you should use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) for better performance:

```
let ops = [];
ops.push({ updateOne: { filter: {name:"foo"}, update: {$inc: {counter:10} }, upsert:true } });
// <add more bulkWrite objects to ops array>
await db.collection('collection-name').bulkWrite([op], {ordered:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understand is you need generic update method for both insert and update to array.It can be done using a dummy Object in array as last element and update that element in case of an insert.

I'm giving here an example :
Initially add dummy object to array :

```
      > db.M4.update({_id:"id"},{"$addToSet":{WatchingList:{UserID:"Last",WatchTimes:0}}},true,true)
      > db.M4.find()
        { "_id" : "id", "WatchingList" : [ { "UserID" : "Last", "WatchTimes" : 0 } ] }
```

//Now below query will handle both insert and update condition :

```
     db.M4.update({_id:"id","WatchingList.UserID":{"$in":["p","Last"]}},{$inc:{"WatchingList.$.WatchTimes":1},"$set":{"WatchingList.$.UserID":"p"}});
```

Remember to run first dummy addition before each update statement.Or you can simply add large number of dummy objects initially itself

Comment: @IT_Layman Could you please explain what is wrong with my answer? I'm just curious to know whether I understood your question or not...

Comment: I apologize for giving you feedback so late. Actually I'm just a MongoDB beginner and don't quite understand your answer. I will appreciate it if you can provide me an example of how it works as to my question.

Comment: @IT_Layman Could Thanks for reply.My idea is to keep a dummy object  { "UserID" : "Last", "WatchTimes" : 0 } in "WatchingList" array and run single update query given.If UserId already exist that query will increase count else it will insert a new user to array.Here Only one query for update and insert provided you have dummy object in array.If you need any more clarification ask me...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for starters, I think you have blundered with your model.
As of the time of this writing, BSON documents have a maximum size of 16MB. Unless very few people will watch a movie, this is going to be a problem.

With your original model, what you want is an update with the usage of `$addToSet` and `$inc`:

```js
db.movies.update(
  { "_id": x },
  { $addToSet:
    { "Watching.List":
      { UserId: foo, "$inc":{ WatchTimes: 1 } }
    }
  }
)
```

**Disclaimer**
I haven't tested this, but it should work since $inc is supposed to create a field if it doesn't exist and $addToSet should create a unique entry to the array.

Comment: I think your concern are right and I have decided to embed the watchingList field in the User document. So the updated documents structure look like:

Comment: Since the change won't affect the problem I asked, I don't need to edit my problem and you don't need to edit your answer.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work. The $inc is shown as a field name on the Mongo shell.

Comment: I added some quotes around the inc, please check. Edit your model as you see fit, I'll happily edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's still not working, the error message shows that $inc is not valid for storage.